# Value in variable disappears when a second submit button is pressed

Tags: php, html, css, post, get

My program first requests the user to enter a customer no. This is achieved when submit 1 button is pressed. Then this customer no is used to extract information from a database and display it. Then the address of this customer has to be altered so this change is asked for on the second form and submit 2 button is pressed.

The problem is:

1. When submit 2 button is pressed the customer no disappears from the `enter customer no` box and the information displayed also disappears.
2. The variable `$custno` has lost its value. I need this variable to update the database.

Why does this happen?
I even used POST for the `submit 1 REQUEST METHOD` and `GET` for the `submit 2 REQUEST METHOD`.

Here is the code I have used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$custno=""; $custexists=1; // $custexists=1 means the customer exists in the database
$newaddress1=""; $newaddress2="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {
if (isset ($_POST["submit1"])) {$custno=$_POST["cust"];

goprintcust($custno,$custexists,$newaddress1,$newaddress2);}}

?>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 14px; top: 10px;">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<br>
<label>Enter Customer No. <input type="number" name="cust" min="1" value="<?php echo $custno; ?>"/></label>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit 1"/><br>
</form>

<?php
function goprintcust($custno,$custexists,$newaddress1,$newaddress2) {
?><div style="position: relative; left: 8px; top:80px;"><?php
// Here search database for $custno and if it exists set $custexists=1
if ($custexists==1) {echo "current data for customer $custno is as follows ..."; // Print the current customer data from the database here
             getnewinput($newaddress1,$newaddress2);}} // we assume the customer exists in the database
                                   // so now get the new data to write into the database


function getnewinput($newaddress1,$newaddress2) {
?>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 14px; top: 60px;">
<table>

<form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"">
<tr><td><label>New Address 1 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress1" value="<?php echo $newaddress1; ?>"/></label></td></tr>
<br>
<tr><td><label>New Address 2 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress2" value="<?php echo $newaddress2; ?>"/></label></td></tr>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="cust" value="<?php echo $custno; ?>">
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit 2"></td></tr><br>
</form>
</table>
<?php             }



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET") {
if (isset ($_GET["submit2"])) {
$newaddress1=$_GET["newaddress1"]; $newaddress2=$_GET["newaddress2"];
getnewinput($newaddress1,$newaddress2);
?><div style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top:130px;"><?php
// Here write the new Address into the database              
echo "<br>"."Database updated for Customer No. ".$custno;
}}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first time you submit the form `Data A` is submitted, the second time you submit the form `Data B` is submitted, UNLESS you also submitted `Data A` TOGETHER WITH `Data B` then `Data A` is lost. (or store it somewhere else, like cookies or sessions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you add `<input type="hidden" name="cust" value="<?php echo $custno; ?>">` to your second form.

When you submit your second form your `$_POST` array is reset, meaning that `$_POST['cust']` no longer exists.  Without that you have `$cust` defined as an empty value.

Comment: <form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"">
    <tr><td><label>New Address 1 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress1" value="<?php echo $newaddress1; ?>"/></label></td></tr>
    <br>
    <tr><td><label>New Address 2 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress2" value="<?php echo $newaddress2; ?>"/></label></td></tr>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="cust" value="<?php echo $custno; ?>">

    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit 2"></td></tr><br>
    </form>
    </table>

Comment: I just copied your recommendation and pasted it in before the 'submit 2' line

Comment: Did you pass $custno into the function that generates that form, `getnewinput()` ?  If not, then that function has no way to call that variable.

Comment: Yes I passed $custno  in to the function from the two points that call it

Comment: When submit 2 is pressed does submit 1 also get re-submitted ?

Comment: No, that's not how forms work.  That's why you put the hidden input in your second form, to ensure that the second form has access to the data.  You need to make sure that `getnewinput($newaddress1,$newaddress2)` reads `getnewinput($custno,$newaddress1,$newaddress2)`, otherwise that function (which generates your second form) will be trying to pull a variable that (within the function) does not exist.